# Serialize proxy object created by cglib

Tags: java, proxy, jersey, jackson, cglib

As title, I use Jersey to return an object as JSON, but the object is created by cglib proxy:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("test")
public Response test() {
    Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
    enhancer.setSuperclass(A.class);
    enhancer.setCallback(new InvocationHandler() {
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            return "my name";
        }
    });
    return Response.ok(enhancer.create()).build();
}

@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public static class A {
    private String name;
}
```

It cannot work because enhancer.create() return a proxy object of class A, not a real object of class A.

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for
>   class MyREST$1 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
>   (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference
>   chain: MyREST$A$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fdcf8406["callbacks"])

Comment: You stated the problem, but what is your expectation of an answer?

Comment: @hotzst my expectation is the way to implement the InvocationHandler to tell the Jackson lib getting the right fields & properties

Answer (score 2):

The problem you encounter is that cglib creates a subclass of your class but does not copy the annotations. At the same time, annotations are not inherited if that is not explicitly defined.

Cglib does not support annotations. To overcome this, you can choose to use another code generation library that supports annotations. I wrote such a library, it is called [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy).

Comment: I think in the "enhancer.setCallback" we can implement the getClass or getAnnotaion or something to cheat Jackson. I am trying your lib, it sounds good